# Why don't we know the electric potential at any point in a circuit, only the difference in the electric potential (voltage)?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, electricity, potential, voltage

Why in circuit analysis, don't we know the electric potential at any point in a circuit?

Comment: This isn't just about circuits. The same thing is true in all of electrostatics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In loop analysis where we apply Kirchhoff's voltage law (the algebraic sum of the potential differences around a loop equals zero) it is only necessary to consider potential differences.

In doing node analysis where we apply Kirchhoff's current law (the algebraic sum of the currents into a node equals zero) we consider the potentials at the different nodes. In order to do this we assign a potential of zero to some node in the circuit. Then the potential at each node is measured with respect to that node.

Although the assignment of zero potential is technically arbitrary, to facilitate the analysis it is usually a node that is common to multiple branches, or the negative terminal of a battery. But no matter where this zero potential is assigned, the potential differences across specific components will be the same.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The electric potential at a point is defined as
$$V(\vec a)=-\int_{\vec{\mathscr O}}^{\vec a}\vec E \cdot d\vec S$$
provided that $\nabla \times \vec E = 0$ (in other words, that there are no changing magnetic fields; you need this condition for the uniqueness of the $V$). In words, voltage is amount of work per charge $q$ needed to bring the charge $q$ from $\vec{\mathscr O}$ to $\vec a$.

However, as you can see, the value of $V(\vec a)$ is dependent on the choice of the reference point $\vec{\mathscr O}$. It is customary to choose it as infinity, since the electric field is in realistic cases zero there, and the lower limit of the integral usually vanishes. Note that this is not the case with "infinite" objects, since the electric field continues to infinity, and we need to use other reference point if we want potentials not to diverge

In realistic cases, if we choose other reference point $\vec{\mathscr O'}$, this corresponds to adding a constant, which doesn't influence the voltage difference (which we are ordinarily interested in):
$$V(\vec a)=-\int_{\vec{\mathscr O'}}^{\vec a}\vec E \cdot d\vec S=-\int_{\vec{\mathscr O'}}^{\vec{\mathscr O}}\vec E \cdot d\vec S-\int_{\vec{\mathscr O}}^{\vec a}\vec E \cdot d\vec S=-\int_{\vec{\mathscr O}}^{\vec a}\vec E \cdot d\vec S+K$$

So, with our circuit, we can (of course, the circuit is realistic scenario, it doesn't have infinite plates) choose the reference point of infinity, and the potential is known at every point (not just the potential drop). However, we usually give potential drop since this is the difference of two potentials, and the choice of a reference point doesn't influence it.

The simplest component of the circuit with well-known potential is the ground or the negative terminal: it is zero. If you then specify the potential difference to the ground/negative terminal, this is the same as the potential.